# MySQL 5.7 stored proc runs forever but running same code through workbench runs fast

Tags: mysql

I have an Ant script, which is called from Eclipse, which calls a set of stored procedures. When it gets to a particular one, that stored proc never finishes. However, when I copy/paste the content of that stored proc and run it in the Workbench, it runs in 5 seconds. What could possibly be the difference?

BTW, the statements that is being run is an INSERT...SELECT.
I'm running this all on my machine right now and all the database access is being done by the same user.

Comment: May be `user` who is connected to the `MySQL`. Or the latency in the network where the server is running.

Comment: It's the same user and I'm running this all on my localhost.